# Top fixed div and datatables overlapping

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

To show some data I use `DataTables` in the page but I need some elements to be fixed on the top of the page, so I need that when the user scroll down the page the `<div class="row top"></div>` stay in the top.

The problem is that the `Show entries` and `Search:` part from the datatables are overlap with the `div` when I use `position: fixed;` and when the user scroll down the page the div elements are hidding except for the `<input>`. Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2773vq9/).

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The usual solution (and in fact I've seen no other) is to just add a padding to the content equal to the height of the fixed header https://jsfiddle.net/L2773vq9/3/

Comment: That Works and for the hidding problem just add `z-index` but if all the page are inside of `<div class="container"></div>` the fixed `<div class="row top"></div>` doesn't respect the width of the `container`. https://jsfiddle.net/L2773vq9/5/